# Replace ASP.NET Core's DI container with external container

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, ioc-containers, asp.net-core

I'm using ASP.NET Core's builtin DI container. It's missing some features I need, so I need to use a third-party container.

The top ones on Nuget are Autofac and StructureMap. SimpleInjector is consistently the fastest, so I'm considering it too.

I have a large code base, so I want to integrate an external container with minimal disruption and refactoring.

Are any of them drop-in replacements for the builtin container?

*I'm not asking a subjective, "which is the best" sort of question. I don't really care. I need to know which is the most compatible.*

Comment: Yeah this is [actually quite complicated](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32797105/7059613), there's no real consensus on the matter. But in theory, most containers work as drop-in replacements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2014/06/17/dependency-injection-in-asp-net-vnext/), all that is required for ASP.NET Core to support your chosen DI container is to implement the `IServiceProvider` interface, using a wrapper around your DI container of choice.  You're then free to use whatever additional features your container provides.

Answer (score 0):

I've integrated Autofac into my system, and other than the few lines of config, it works as a drop-in replacement.

Other containers probably work too, but I can only confirm for Autofac.